# Perform a correlation between each cell of a two vector dataframe in R, where each cell refers to the name of a vector in another dataframe

Tags: r, loops, correlation

I have a dataframe i created with expand.grid called "list.paired" with two vectors as follows:

```
               Var1             Var2
1          measure1              measure1 
2          measure2              measure1
3          measure3              measure1
4          measure4              measure1
5          measure5              measure1
6          measure6              measure1
7          measure7              measure1
8          measure2              measure2
9          measure2              measure3
10         ... and so on, detailing every combination of the 7 variables
```

Each measure refers to a vector in another dataframe. E.g., longdata$measure1.

To reference longdat$measure1, for example, I can use the following code:

```
eval(parse(text = paste("longdat$",list.paired[1,1], sep =""))
```

I'd like to make a loop that performs a correlation between each combination of list.paired, where it refers to data stored in longdat. e.g.,:

```
x = eval(parse(text = paste("longdat$",list.paired[2,1],".long", sep =""))) #longdat$measure2
y = eval(parse(text = paste("longdat$",list.paired[2,2],".long", sep =""))) #longdat$measure1
cor(x, y)
```

I've so far been unsuccessful designing a loop for this that will cycle through each pair of variables in list.paired. I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested for loop:

```
for (vm1 in list.paired$Var1) {
    for(vm2 in list.paired$Var2) {
        x = eval(parse(text = paste("longdat$",vm1,".long", sep =""))) #longdat$measure2
        y = eval(parse(text = paste("longdat$",vm2,".long", sep =""))) #longdat$measure1
        cor(x, y)
    }
}
```

This will be fairly slow though. A faster way would be to `cbind` your vectors into two separate matrices `m1` and `m2` and then run `cor(m1,m2)`. According to the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cor.html) of `cor`: *If x and y are matrices then the covariances (or correlations) between the columns of x and the columns of y are computed.*

Answer (score 0):

I think that approach has much redundancy because cor(measure1,measure2) is the same as cor(measure2,measure1) and cor(measure1,measure1) is 1. In reality you have only 21 unique combinations ((7 choose 2)).

Might this approach work?

```
 # your long data
 df<- data.frame(col1 = runif(100),col2 = runif(100),col3 = runif(100),col4 = 
 runif(100),col5 = runif(100),col6 = runif(100),col7 = runif(100))

 # your vector with correlations between unique combinations of columns
 cor.vec <- apply(combn(7,2), 2, function(idx) cor(df[,idx[1]],df[,idx[2]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following dataframes:

```
list.paired <- data_frame(
  Var1 = str_c("measure", rep(1:3, each = 3)),
  Var2 = str_c("measure", rep(1:3, 3))
)

longdat <- data_frame(
  measure1 = rnorm(10),
  measure2 = rnorm(10),
  measure3 = rnorm(10)
)
```

A loop option could be:

```
results <- list()
for (v1 in list.paired$Var1)
  for (v2 in list.paired$Var2) {
    results <- c(results, cor(longdat[v1], longdat[v2]))
    names(results[[length(results)]]) <- paste(v1, "*", v2)
  }
```

Or using the `purrr` package (`mapply` could do about the same):

```
purrr:pmap(
  list.paired,
  function(Var1, Var2) {
    res <- cor(longdat[[Var1]], longdat[[Var2]])
    names(res) <- paste(Var1, "*", Var2)
    return(res)
  }
)
```

But maybe all you need is just `cor(longdat)`?